# Image annotation in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.forms-styles

I am new to Xamarin.Forms and looking for a help on two questions.

1. I would like take a picture with the camera or download one from a website. Once the image is loaded, to be able to draw on the image with stylus or finger. Once satisfied with the annotation, save the image back. Does anyone know of a tool that I could use to help speed up this dev effort?
2. Is there a way application can figure out if the image that is being saved is of good quality, meaning not blurry or with disturbance?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions / information.

Comment: Hey im looking to do a similar thing in a xamarin forms app, did you get anywhere with this?  I'm thinking it's something that I will need to create a custom control for on each of the platforms I am supporting.